# Tar: File changed as we read it/ file removed before we read it Errors

Tags: backup, tar, error-handling

I'm trying to create an automated backup script using the tar command:

```
tar -czg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/snapshot_2020-10-12 -f /home/user/BackupArchiv/backup_2020-10-12/backupfull.tar.gz /home/user
```

When I try to execute the script, I always get the error messages "file removed before it was read" because of system file and "file changed as we read it" because of the backup file that *of course* changes during the command. The problem is that these two errors interrupt the script and stop it from continuing. I've already found some solutions where other people added the "--warning" option but my script just ignored that for some reason.
How do I get the script to continue after these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the `BackupArchiv`-Directory.

`tar -czg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/snapshot_2020-10-12 -f /home/user/BackupArchiv/backup_2020-10-12/backupfull.tar.gz /home/user --exclude /home/user/BackupArchiv`

Comment: `gtar` is not recommended for incremental backups as it fails to extract incrementals for non-trivial changes. The main purpose for backups are restores, so better use tools to backup that have been verified to reliably support restores as well.